# Вложенный цикл for java

Tags: java

не могу понять как строить логику, подскажите пожалуйста. Для каждого значение `pacient` получить значение `report` и отправить его всем `users`.
все эти данных хранятся в отдельных `List<String>`, получаю их из других методов других классов.
для формирования отчета делаю такую схему

```
    for(int i = 0; i < pacient.size(); i++){
    String pacientL = pacient.get(i);
  for(String reportsL : reports){

  for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++){
    String usersL = pacient.get(i);

 .....

  } 
 }
}
```

В итоге получаю 16 сообщений, хотя в базе имеется всего 2 `pacient`, соответственно должно быть 2 `report` и отправлено контактам. Что не так делаю?

---

получение массивов

```
static List<String> paceint_number_list = new ArrayList<>();
static List<String> report_list = new ArrayList<>();

  String query2 = "select * FROM pacient_status WHERE agreement = 1";
            paceint_number = rsQ.getString("paceint_number");
            blood = rsQ.getString("blood");

            paceint_number_list.add(paceint);
            blood_list.add(blood);  
      report = "\u2705" +" Готов анализ: " +car_number +
                    + "\ud83d\udfe0Кровь  \n" +blood + "\n" ;

      report_list.add(report);
```

Comment: не совсем понятно, а report для каждого pacient, вы как получаете?

Comment: В базе таблица, там pacient и к нему еще несколько параметров. Значение pacient  записываю в `List<String>` , а остальные значения складываю в переменную ввиде отчета, допустим `"report = "Айди" +pacien_id + "какой-то показатель" +pokazatel;` и это передаю

Comment: дело в том, что вы перебираете список reports в цикле, а он не зависит от pacient.

Comment: тогда я совсем запутался) а каким методом можно указать зависимость?

Comment: Более того, вы и меня запутали) А нужен ли вообще этот цикл? Может кините побольше кода? Как pacient заполняется?

Comment: До меня дошло, наверное) наверное нужно получить список всех пациентов одним запросом, а отдельным получать остальные данные. Тогда получится что report формируется для каждого значения. Сейчас попробую)

Comment: Вобщем, если кому нужно будет)  `String[] greportsArr = new String[greportsL.size()]; 
for(int i = 0; i < pacientnumL.size(); i++){
  
  pacientn_numberL = pacientnumL.get(i);
  
  String reportsL = greportsArr[i]; `
Перевел отчеты обычный Array и после for доставал отчет с тем же порядковым номером, что и номер записи. вроде получилось